# Combining Two column give a nan output

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I am having two dataframe column y_test and x_test they have same size of rows my trouble is while combining those two dataframe i am getting y_test column names label is shown as nan...The detailed image is shown below
[image]

Code i have used of this is

```
x_test['label'] = y_test
```

did need anymore details please mention i will provide

Comment: why didn't you tri y_test['label']

Comment: bescause the y_test is  a series type dataframe

Comment: if i try that how it will differ from what i done

Comment: Are `print(type(x_test.index))` and `print(type(y_test.index))` the same?

Comment: No type(x_test) = <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> and type(y_test) = <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> both are various

Comment: but same like that i have done for train they are also different but it was combining very well.that what i am confused

Comment: type(x_train) = <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> and type(y_train)= <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>

Comment: very thank for your reply...can you able to identify what happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the puzzle by converting the y_test(series) to array then make combining.

```
y_test = np.array(y_test)
x_test['label'] = y_test
```

But really i am confused why combining the series and dataframe shows a nan result?